# Partly loading a PDF into memory

Tags: ios, pdf, memory, core-graphics

is there a way to load (large) PDF files only partly? So, let's say: Don't load the complete PDF file, but only the first 5 pages.

Because I'm actually handling large PDF files (30 - 50 MB) and when I call CGPDFRetain the whole document, so the complete 30-50 MB are retained in memory.

Can somebody help me with that? Is it possible to fetch single pages out of PDF without first loading the complete PDF into memory?

Can somebody help me with that problem?

**Update:
Due to the fact, that my app needs to support offline access, the PDFs should be loaded from local storage.**

**Update 2: I tried different strategies by now, but the app is still on memory edge, because I'm loading my PDF completely into the memory in one single step. But somehow it should be possible to support big PDF files, shouldn't it?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what CGPDFRetain is, so I might be totally off. PDF is designed in such a way that you only need parts of it to render it correctly. There is something called a "web optimized" PDF which has its objects arranged in a special way. Every webserver is able to send a byte range of a document, and these two mechanisms allow the partial loading of a PDF.

You should elaborate where you load the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

It's not like this. CGPDFDocument POINTS to your a disk space and has parts cached in memory, but never the whole document.

There are some problems with CGPDFDocument getting too greedy with memory, but in that case just destroy and re-create the CGPDFDocument and you're fine. Otherwise, your app might just crash after CGPDFDocument has allocated too much memory.